# SQL JOINS not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

```
1. tblJobs

JobID       int primary key

JobTypeID   int

JobClientID int

JobStaffID  int

....

2. tblContacts

ContactID   int primary key

ContactName varchar

....

3. tblJobTypes

TypeID      int primary key

TypeName    varchar
```

I can SELECT data from these table with this SQL...

```
SELECT tblContacts.ContactName, tblContacts.ContactID, 
tblJobs.JobID, tblJobs.JobTypeID, tblJobs.JobClientID, tblJobs.JobStaffID, 
tblJobTypes.* FROM (tblJobs LEFT JOIN tblJobTypes ON tblJobs.JobTypeID = tblJobTypes.TypeID)  LEFT JOIN tblContacts ON tblJobs.JobClientID = tblContacts.ContactID;
```

An example row from the SQL...

```
| ContactName| ContactID | JobID | JobTypeID | JobClientID | JobStaffID |TypeID | TypeName |

| Mr Contact |       290 |   341 |         3 |         290 |        202 |     3 | Enquiry  |
```

As you can see this SQL joins the tblJobs.JobClientID to tblContacts.ContactID(290).
This is how I get tblContacts.JobStaffID (202).

How can I modify the SQL to get tblContacts.ContactName?

I've tried joining tables twice but with no success.

Comment: What do you mean? You got tblContacts.ContactName in your `SELECT` as it is.

Comment: Man this query is hard to read, better provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `JobStaffID` is a foreign key relating to `tblContacts.ContactID` you're correct in assuming that you need to join the `tblContacts` table twice - but you have to give it different aliases in each join like this:

```
SELECT 
    c1.ContactName as ClientName, c1.ContactID as ClientID, 
    c2.ContactName as StaffName,  c2.ContactID as StaffID, 
    j.JobID, j.JobTypeID, j.JobClientID, j.JobStaffID, 
    jt.TypeID, jt.TypeName     
FROM tblJobs j
LEFT JOIN tblJobTypes jt ON j.JobTypeID = jt.TypeID
LEFT JOIN tblContacts c1 ON j.JobClientID = c1.ContactID
LEFT JOIN tblContacts c2 ON j.JobStaffID  = c2.ContactID;
```

And while at it you might want to use aliases for all tables to reduce the query text.

Comment: The answer from jpw has put me on the right track.  It says here to avoid comments like 'Thanks' so how can I 'vote' for this answer?